# UnExpectedException in Play Framework

Tags: playframework

I'm getting below error, when I remove some unncessary code block. What could be the issue.

`While applying class play.classloading.enhancers.LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer on controllers.DisputeController`

To avoid this error Im keeping that unnecessary code. Please help me in this regard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was some problems with variable enhancements in version 1.2.3. A lot of them are corrected in version 1.2.4 see https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/1133-javassist-unset-variable-error-when-applying-localvariablesnamesenhancer for example

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with 1.2.4  and you have updated your hibernate version, it is possible (in special cases) that you encounter this error.

> The solution to fix this is simpel, but very well hidden. When you
>   ftch the new hibernate version. A new version of javassistant is
>   fetched as well. Play can't work with this new version. So the trick
>   is to overrule the new version and downgrade to the older version as
>   added in play. to do so, you have to add the follwoing line to your
>   required part of conf/dependecies.yml
>
> ```
> - javassist -> javassist 3.9.0.GA
> ```
>
> (please remember to run play dependencies --sync (including --sync!) )
>   and play netbeansify of play eclipsify.

Source: http://blog.jerrevds.be/article/localvariablesnamesenhancer-exception-play